# Does AES/CBC really require IV parameter?

Tags: java, aes, password-encryption, cbc-mode

I am writing a simple app to encrypt my message using AES / CBC (mode). As my understanding CBC mode requires IV parameter but I don't know why my code work without IV parameter used. Anyone can explain why? Thanks.

**The encrypted message printed: T9KdWxVZ5xStaisXn6llfg==    without exception.**

```java
public class TestAES {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            byte[] salt = new byte[8];
            new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);

            SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec("myPassword".toCharArray(), salt, 100, 128);

            SecretKey tmp = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher enCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            enCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            // enCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

            byte[] cipherBytes = enCipher.doFinal("myMessage".getBytes());
            String cipherMsg = BaseEncoding.base64().encode(cipherBytes);

            System.out.println("Encrypted message: " + cipherMsg);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It works because Java picks a random IV. you can use `enCipher.getIV()` after init to see the values (and sent them to the other side).

Comment: https://doridori.github.io/Android-Security-Beware-of-the-default-IV/ As you were using `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` it was probably using the old `AndroidOpenSSL` implementation, which (sadly) defaults to a `[0]` IV

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it is used without an IV, for certain types of ciphers including AES, it implicitly uses 0 IV.  See Cipher class [documentation](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/crypto/Cipher.html#init%28javacard.security.Key,%20byte%29).

The disadvantage of a null IV (or a deterministic IV) is that it is vulnerable to dictionary attacks. The requirement for IV is to prevent the same plain text block producing the same cipher text every time.

Comment: Actually Java SE uses a random IV if you specify none. Your link points to Java card API. If you do not specify one you get a randome one, you do need to retrieve it with `cipher.getIV()` if you did not set it.

Comment: Depends on the `Provider` in use also https://doridori.github.io/Android-Security-Beware-of-the-default-IV

Answer (score 1):

Like other users have said, it depends on the JCE provider. **Java SE** generates a random IV for you if you specify none.

Only **Android**<sup>1</sup> and Javacard API use a blank IV, which is non-conforming to the Java Crypto spec, [which states](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#init(int,%20java.security.Key)):

> If this cipher requires any algorithm parameters that cannot be derived from the given `key`, the underlying cipher implementation is supposed to **generate** the required parameters itself (using provider-specific default or random values) if it is being initialized for encryption or key wrapping, and raise an `InvalidKeyException` if it is being initialized for decryption or key unwrapping. The generated parameters can be retrieved using `getParameters` or `getIV` (if the parameter is an **IV**).

If you do not specify the IV, in Java SE you get a random one, and will need to retrieve it with `cipher.getIV()` and store it, as it will be needed for decryption.

But better yet, generate a random IV yourself and provide it via `IvParameterSpec`.

```
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
    rnd.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES"), ivParams);

    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>That could be because Android is *Java-esque*, like the *[Eminem-esque](https://youtu.be/gsEvdamYIKU?t=9)* ad. Just guessing, that's all.</sub>