# How does an IV work and what would be the best way to store it?

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, node-crypto

I want to encrypt and decrypt strings. I'm using Nodejs crypto for this. I've read that when encrypting and decrypting it's highly recommended to use an IV. I want to store the encrypted data inside a MySQL database and decrypt it later when needed. I understand that I need the IV also for the decryption process. But what exactly is an IV and how should I store it? I read something about that an IV does not to be kept secret. Does this mean I can store it right next to the encrypted data it belongs to?

Comment: How an IV is used, and what is required, recommended, or even permitted, depends on the cipher type and mode of operation, which you don't specify. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for some basics; this is not really a programming question, but there are at least hundreds and probably thousands of Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX about a great many of the possible cases. Yes, an IV need not be secret, and storing and/or transmitting it adjacent to the ciphertext is a simple and common approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it's highly recommended to use an IV

No, it's *required* or you'll not get a fully secure ciphertext in most circumstances. At the very minimum, not supplying an IV for the same key and plaintext message will result in identical ciphertext, which will leak information to an adversary. In other words: encryption would be deterministic, and that's not a property that you want from a cipher. For CTR and GCM mode you may well leak all of the plaintext message though...

> But what exactly is an IV ... ?

An IV just consists of binary bits. It's size and contents depend on the mode of operation (CBC/CTR/GCM). Generally it needs either to be a nonce or randomized.

CBC mode requires a randomized IV of 16 bytes; generally a cryptographically secure random number generator is used for that.

CTR mode commonly specifies both a nonce and the initial counter value within the IV of 16 bytes. So you already need to put the nonce in the left hand bytes (lowest index). This nonce may be randomized, but then it should be large enough (e.g. 12 bytes) to avoid the birthday problem.

GCM mode requires just a nonce of 12 bytes.

> and how should I store it

Anyway you can store the bytes, as long as they can be retrieved or regenerated during decryption. If you need text you may need to encode it using base 64 or hexadecimals (this goes for the ciphertext as well, of course).

> I read something about that an IV does not to be kept secret.

That's correct.

> Does this mean I can store it right next to the encrypted data it belongs to?

Correct, quite often the IV is simply prefixed to the ciphertext; if you know the block cipher and mode of operation then the size is predetermined after all.